# fastify and ajv schema validation

Tags: javascript, ajv

I am trying to validate the querystring parameter 'hccid' as shown below. Seems like the validation is not working for me. Can some one see what I am missing?

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  ajv: {
        removeAdditional: true,
        useDefaults:      true,
        coerceTypes:      true
    }
});


const schema = {
    querystring: {
       hccid: { type: 'string' }
    }
};

// Declare a route
 fastify.get('/hello', {schema}, function (request, reply) {
    const hccid = request.query.hccid;
    reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
});

// Run the server!
fastify.listen(3000, function (err) {
if (err) throw err
  console.log(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`)
});
```

So with that code, I should get a schema validation exception when I call the service with a total new queryparam `abc` just like I shown below

```
http://localhost:3000/hello?abc=1
```

but there was no error. I got the response back `{"hello":"world"}`

I also tried removing the queryparam all together `http://localhost:3000/hello`

and I still got `{"hello":"world"}`

so obviously the validation is not working. What is missing in my code? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The schema is not correct at all, please read the docs on JSON Schema.

Comment: thank you. +1 for your time looking into it. I corrected the schema and it works now. I posted the corrected schema below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this schema structure solved my problem. Just in case if someone wants to check it out if they run into similar issue.

```
const querySchema = {
    schema: {
       querystring: {
         type: 'object',
           properties: {
             hccid: {
               type: 'string'
             }
         },
       required: ['hccid']
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Thanks man. Looked in the docs but somehow skipped it. Had to look all over the internet to find your answer and remember to search again in docs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you can use the `querystring` or `query` to validate the query string and `params` to validate the route params.

Params would be:

- `/api/garage/:id` where `id` is the param accessible `request.params.id`
- `/api/garage/:plate` where `plate` is the param accessible at `request.params.plate`

Example for param validation would be:

```js
const getItems = (req, reply) => {
  const { plate } = req.params;
  delete req.params.plate;
  reply.send(plate);
};

const getItemsOpts = {
  schema: {
    description: "Get information about a particular vehicle present in garage.",
    params: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        plate: {
          type: "string",
          pattern: "^[A-Za-z0-9]{7}$",
        },
      },
    },
    response: {
      200: {
        type: "array",
      },
    },
  },
  handler: getItems,
};

fastify.get("/garage/:plate", getItemsOpts);
done();
```

Query / Querystring would be:

- `/api/garage/id?color=white&size=small` where `color` and `size` are the two querystrings accessible at `request.query.color` or `request.query.size` .

Please refer to the above answer as an example fro query validation.

> ### Validation
>
> The route validation internally relies upon [Ajv v6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv/v/6.12.6) which is a
> high-performance JSON Schema validator. Validating the input is very
> easy: just add the fields that you need inside the route schema, and
> you are done!
>
> The supported validations are:
>
> - `body`: validates the body of the request if it is a POST, PUT, or    PATCH method.
> - `querystring` or `query`: validates the query string.
> - `params`: validates the route params.
> - `headers`: validates the request headers.

[1] Fastify Validation: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Validation-and-Serialization/#validation

[2] Ajv@v6: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv/v/6.12.6

[3] Fastify Request: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Request/