# node validate request params using AJV

Tags: node.js, validation, json-schema-validator, ajv

I am creating an API which accept request params and I want to validate if the param is valid mongo ObjectId.

API Signature:- https://example.com/test/:id

Want to check if **id** is Object id

PS - I am using AJV middleware to validate

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233737/8690463

Answer (score 0):

AJV doesn't support custom validations check this https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/967#issuecomment-470428858

But you can use you own regex to validate the objectId:

```
user_id: {type: 'string', pattern: '^[a-f\\d]{24}$'},
```

The full example could be:

```
{
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      user_id: {type: 'string', pattern: '^[a-f\\d]{24}$'},
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a custom format to ajv.

the code below will d that.

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const Ajv = require('ajv').default;
const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });
ajv.addFormat('objectid', {
  type: 'string',
  validate: (data) => {
    return ObjectId.isValid(data);
  },
});
```

Then in your schema file you can add this like below,

```
"userId": {
  "type": "string",
  "format": "objectid",
},
```